# {golem} template for non-RStudio IDE users

Tags: r, golem

Is there a progammatic way to start a new {golem} app from template? As a VSCode user, it bothers me a little having to open RStudio just to create a new project from template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `golem::create_golem()` to create golem apps using command line. There is no requirements for an IDE.
Note that any new project template for RStudio requires a R function in the package behind the scene. Chances are all templates have this function exported to the users.